# QtCreator + CMAKE refuses to build project if Q_OBJECT is included in header file

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I am newish to C++, CMake and especially Qt and QtCreator.

Basically, I have a header file that looks as follows:

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkRequest>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QStringList>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    void clearValues();
    ~MainWindow();
    void TestConnection(quint8 requestedObject) const;
    void ReplyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply);

private slots:
    void on_objectType_currentIndexChanged(int index);
    void on_searchPhrase_returnPressed();
    void on_searchButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QNetworkAccessManager *netManager;
    QNetworkReply *netReply;
    QNetworkReply *repoReply;
    QByteArray dataBuffer;
    QPixmap *img;
    QStringList objOptions;
    quint8 *contactIndex;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

unfortunately, that "Q_OBJECT" in there causes the build to not....build, providing these errors;

```
mocs_compilation.cpp.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __cdecl MainWindow::on_searchPhrase_returnPressed(void)" (?on_searchPhrase_returnPressed@MainWindow@@AEAAXXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl MainWindow::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@MainWindow@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)

hubUI.exe:-1: error: LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

:-1: error: ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

However, if I delete the Q_OBJECT, everything builds and runs fine (but obviously without Qt's Slots and such).

So, is there a way to have my cake and eat it too? What am I doing wrong?

Here's my CMAKE:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(hubUI VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Network)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        mainwindow.h
        mainwindow.cpp
        mainwindow.ui
)

include_directories(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(hubUI
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
# Define target properties for Android with Qt 6 as:
#    set_property(TARGET hubUI APPEND PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR
#                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android)
# For more information, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-executable.html#target-creation
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(hubUI SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
# Define properties for Android with Qt 5 after find_package() calls as:
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
    else()
        add_executable(hubUI
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(hubUI PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)
target_link_libraries(hubUI PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Network)

# Qt for iOS sets MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER automatically since Qt 6.1.
# If you are developing for iOS or macOS you should consider setting an
# explicit, fixed bundle identifier manually though.
if(${QT_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 6.1.0)
  set(BUNDLE_ID_OPTION MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example.hubUI)
endif()
set_target_properties(hubUI PROPERTIES
    ${BUNDLE_ID_OPTION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS hubUI
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(hubUI)
endif()
```

Comment: have you implemented `on_searchPhrase_returnPressed`?